# Stopping Eclipse from spell-checking e-mail addresses

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

I am using Eclipse 3.7SR2 and I have an issue with the Java editor spell-checker marking e-mail addresses:

[image: Screen shot of Eclipse spell-checking e-mail addresses]

Perhaps I am a bit obsessive, but I really dislike seeing those red blots - if not for any other reason, then just because real spelling errors could be missed in the crowd.

Is there a way to fix this on a permanent basis without disabling spell-checking completely?

**UPDATE:**

Adding the "word" in question (e.g. `@example.com`) to the user dictionary manually and restarting Eclipse does not seem to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to get Eclipse to ignore email addresses using a User Dictionary:

1. Go to **Window** -> **Preferences**
2. Expand the panels to see **General** > **Editors** > **Text Editors** > **Spelling**.
3. In the **User defined dictionary** field, enter a full path for a text file you'd like to keep the dictionary in. Or use the Browse... button if you already have a text file somewhere.
4. Edit the file you have just specified in a text editor, and enter the two parts of the email address on separate lines; eg, for the example in this question, you would need to add "john" and "example.com".
5. Repeat for any new email domains or user names that the spell checker flags.

This solution is not obvious because the spell checker highlights the "@" symbol too. But if "@example.com" is added to the dictionary, it does not stop the spell checker from complaining. You have to manually add the domain excluding the "@".

Comment: Thanks, this actually worked - it never occurred to me to remove the `@` symbol from the user dictionary entry, since the spell checker highlighting is completely misleading...

Answer (score 1):

Um, i can't find one. On the other hand, an inelegant solution would involve putting a capitalisation in the email address.

So bharal@gmail.com will get the error, but bharal@gMail.com will not. Or bharal@Gmail.com, which reads better.